# Default.html is not being served by sharepoint foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a SPF 2010 site which has a default.htm page which I want to get opened whenever I hit the site.

Let me know. 
RHM

Comment: Have you changed the page to the site's homepage in SharePoint Designer (Right-Click)?

Comment: Yes I did. Still when I am opening the spf 2010 site like from url http://localhost it gives me prompt to download my homepage not rendering it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the page has been set as the homepage and SharePoint is prompting for download, confirm that your web application Browser File Handling is set to "Permissive"... if it's set to "Strict" that could be what's forcing the browser to attempt to download.

`Central Administration > Manage Web Applications > Select Web Application > General Settings`